# JavaScript Test RegExp function non-latin characters bug

Tags: javascript, regex

Well, I have noticed this during using console.

```
> var a = new RegExp('\\b' + "абв" + '\\b', "gim");
> a.test("абв");
false

> var b = new RegExp("абв", "gim");
> b.test("абв");
true
```

And then with latin characters:

```
> var c = new RegExp('\\b' + "abc" + '\\b', "gim");
> c.test("abc");
true
```

I would glad to read your suggestions about fixing this.

Comment: The problem is the word boundaries, you need to create DIY boundaries in this case. `var a = /(^| )абв( |$)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` refers only to word boundaries in an ASCII perception. You can create **DIY** boundaries. Also if you already know the pattern will remain constant, use a regular expression literal as follows:

```
/(^| )абв( |$)/.test("абв"); // true
```